# How to configure wireless adapter with Ubuntu Linux 20.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I'm new to Linux so looking for quite basic instructions...

Running Ubuntu Linux 20.04

I recently built my first PC and bought a Ubit AC 1200Mbps Bluetooth WiFi Card. Bluetooth is working but wifi is not.

When I emailed customer support, I was linked to the following drivers with no other information:

ATH9K: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k 
ATH10K for QCA9377: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath10k 
ATH10K for QCA6174A: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/xenial/main/updates/linux-firmware

I have tried to follow the [Linux wifi troubleshooting guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html.en) but not had any success. This is the output I get from `lshw -C network`:

*-network
description: Ethernet interface
product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:22:00.0
logical name: enp34s0
version: 15
serial: 2c:f0:5d:72:83:b7
size: 1Gbit/s
capacity: 1Gbit/s
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.82 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
resources: irq:36 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcb04000-fcb04fff memory:fcb00000-fcb03fff
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
physical id: 1
logical name: docker0
serial: 02:42:bc:67:39:b2
capabilities: ethernet physical
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes

My understanding is that neither of these ethernet interfaces correspond to the wifi adapter (the first is the ethernet cable I have temporarily plugged in and the second is for Docker).

How would I go about compiling drivers to make the adapter compatible?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

---

**UPDATE**

After entering BIOS it was apparent that the motherboard was not recognising anything in the expected pcie port. I moved the card to another port and now its working.

It turns out that the original pcie port becomes unavailable when SSD is installed in a particular port.

The key to this problem was viewing the board explorer in BIOS to see which hardware pieces were recognised by the motherboard.

Comment: Can you find your card with an lspci or "lspci -v" and add the relevant output to your question?

Comment: I believe the card does not show up for the same reason as in lshw. The only interface that seems relevant is 22:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15) but I believe this is for the wired connection?

Comment: Michael, that would almost certainly mean your motherboard doesn't see that card.  If you do a slow boot of your system, is it shown?

Comment: I'll have to do some research to perform a slow boot. I will get back to you shortly. Thanks for your advice Gerard!

Comment: slow boot:  in the bios disable the "splash screen" or something like that.  BTW, ready for the Brexit, Michael?

Comment: Okay, I'm going to attempt a slow boot although not 100% sure of what I'm looking for. And yes, I heard today that ships are lining up on the coast haha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117207/discussion-between-michael-and-gerard-h-pille).